# Como fazer uma submissão de formulário sem formulário?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A pergunta pode parecer estranha. Mas em uma determinada página gostaria de fazer uma `submit`, como de um formulário, ao clicar em um botão, porém sem a presença do formulário no HTML.

Existe alguma maneira de simular a submissão de um formulário, sem ele existir na página?

Exemplo:

```
<!-- Faz um paranauê para submeter a página via post sem formulário -->
<button id="submit"></button>
```

**Observação**: Eu não preciso de preenchimento de formulário, nem nada. Eu só preciso apenas que, quando se clica no botão, uma submissão de formulário seja enviada (método POST). E não se trata de uma requisição ajax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sendo apenas a necessidade de enviar o form, você poderia usar ajax, mas não me parece o caso, ainda sim existe um atributo do html5 novo que pode lhe ajudar, é o `form="..."` e criar um formulário oculto (assim não necessitará de javascript):

```
<!--// formulário oculto -->
<form action="rota" method="POST" id="meuformulario">
  <input type="hidden" name="chave1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="chave2" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="chave3" value="3">
</form>

...

<p>....</p>


...    

<button type="submit" form="meuformulario" value="Chamar">Chamar (trigger)</button>
```

<sub>Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button</sub>

Além disto ainda é possivel controlar o form com outros atributos pelo `<button>`:

- `formaction` trocar o action do formulário apontado pelo atributo `form=""`
- `formenctype` este atributo trocar o `ecntype` do formulário  apontado pelo atributo `form=""`, valores que podem ser usados:

  - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `multipart/form-data`
  - `text/plain`
- `formmethod` troca o method do `<form>` apontado pelo atributo `form=""`
- `formnovalidate` troca o valor de `<form novalidate="">` apontado pelo atributo `form=""` é um valor Boleano.
- `formtarget` troca o `target` da instancia de janela que pretende que a requisição seja feita, exemplos de valores aceitos:

  - `_self`
  - `_blank`
  - `_parent`
  - `_top`

Exemplo:

```
<button formaction="/pagina" formenctype="multipart/form-data" formmethod="POST" formtarget="_blank">
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, há uma maneira. Você pode fazer da mesma forma que você usa pra submeter um formulário via javascript, porém você vai usar apenas o que for criado pelo `document.createElement`

Assim:

```
var fake_form = document.createElement('form');

fake_form.method = 'POST';

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function()
{
     fake_form.submit();
});
```